# routes with query result in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, callback, devise, routes

I receive a callback at a specific path, together with a query result:

```
/auth/callback?oauth_token=00b4-2a6e-4624-88bf-18&oauth_verifier=406123
```

When I try to match this route to a particular action

```
  devise_scope :user do 
    match 'auth/callback'  => 'my_authorization#callback'
  end
```

I got an error message:

```
Could not find devise mapping for path "/auth/callback?oauth_token=85d3&oauth_verifier=406123". Maybe you forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block? For example: devise_scope :user do match "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller" end
```

I suspect that may be the query result after question mark messed it up. Am I right? How can I map it to a particular action?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've scoped this under `:user`. So I believe this route would match `/user/auth/callback` and not just `/auth/callback`.